# Do I need php-mysql? If I already have nginx, php-fpm and mariadb-server?

Tags: debian

Do I need to install it if I already have nginx, php-fpm and mariadb-server?
What is php-mysql for?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want your PHP code to be able to access a MySQL (or MariaDB) database? If yes, then you need this package. It provides the necessary PHP functions.

Comment: I am able to access mysql through my website now without php-mysql installed, so I'm curious

Comment: @user584604 there are multiple php packages providing sql connectivity. Moreover, php-mysql is a meta package. The actual package is a dependency of it. Removing the metapackage can likely hinder a distribution upgrade much later.